# jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException:SHA1 digest error for META-INF/CERT.RSA android error while updating application

Tags: java, android, sha, meta-inf

I am getting this error while i am updating my android application, i tried signing new Application on same system there is no problem with that,
[image]when updating the same application i got this error.
I need help, i searched but nothing worked for me.
[image]
I am using android studio when i updated studio to 2.2 preview 1 i am getting this error.
java 1.8.0_92 installed in my System.

Comment: Note-For maven based projects, take a careful look at <plugin> ordering. Make sure the jar is signed only after obfuscation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution , just extract apk with 7zip and deleted the META-INF folder and re-signed Apk
[image]

Comment: I really need your help on this problem. It is killing me. I have unzipped (using Linux platform here) the file, deleted the folder above and now am left with the extracted folder. how do I create an apk file from that?

Comment: after deleting folder you just need to release a new signed apk

Comment: i guess there is bug in Android studio 2.2 Preview 1

Comment: Could it be Android Studio Preview? Because I never had this issue in Android Studio 2.1 stable. Even after deleting that folder, I still had issues after uploading the apk. I will switch back to my 2.1 Android Studio

Comment: It is Android Studio 2.2 Preview issue;

Comment: Has someone reported this bug for Android Studio 2.2 preview?

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

Rebuild Project > Clean Project (Is this necessary?)> Generate Signed APK